# How can I make this simple fortran 90 code faster?

Tags: c++, performance, fortran90, gfortran

I am trying to compare computation times of a simple code to compute sum of cubes of integers using both Fortran 90 and C++ since I had heard they are fast on similar levels. I use gfortran and g++ (on Mac OSX) to compile these codes.

Can somebody kindly point out why the Fortran 90 code takes so much more time (49 seconds) than its equivalent C++ code (12 seconds)? Only thing I know that C++ is row major and Fortran is column major but I don't think that is relevant for these codes. 
How can I make this fortran90 code faster? Any tips will be appreciated. Thanks.

Fortran code and compiling with `gfortran -o bb1 code15.f90`

```fortran
program code15 
implicit none

double precision, dimension(:), allocatable :: a
integer (kind=8) :: n,i
real (kind=16) :: ssum
real :: ts1, ts2

call cpu_time(ts1)
n = 1600000000
allocate(a(n))
ssum=0.0

do i=1,n
    a(i)=i
    ssum=ssum+a(i)*a(i)*a(i)
end do

print *, 'final sum ', ssum
deallocate(a) 
call cpu_time(ts2)
print *,'the time taken is ',ts2-ts1

end program
```

Output is

```
 final sum    1.63840000204800000399876515667619840E+0036
 the time taken is    48.6228256
```

C++ code and compiling with `g++ -o bb1 code10.cpp`

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;

main()
{
    long int n,i;
    long double ssum;

    clock_t starttime = clock();
    n=1600000000;
    double *a = new double[n];
    ssum=0;

    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        a[i]=i+1;
        ssum=ssum+a[i]*a[i]*a[i];
    }

    cout << "final sum " << ssum << endl;
    delete [ ]a;
    cout << "the time taken is "
         << (double)( clock() - starttime ) / (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC
         << endl;
}
```

output is

```
final sum 1.6384e+36
the time taken is 12.0104
```

Comment: Any particular reason to create an array to store `n -> n+1`? I may be mistaken, but doesn't FORTRAN iterate through all the variables to find what you want? Meaning it would iterate through 1.6 billion variables before finding what you want?

Comment: that is because in fortran array indexing starts with 1, so it is 1,2,3.. but in C++ array indexing starts with 0, so it is 0,1,2,3

Comment: There's no point comparing performance without turning on optimisation (e.g. `g++ -O2 ...`).

Comment: i turned the `-O2` flag on `gfortran -O2 -o bb1 code15.f90`, slightly faster at 43.8 seconds

Comment: Did you examine assembly code? Does one compiler make use of vectorization? `long double` is probably an 80-bit floating point number (supported in hardware). What is `real (kind=16)`? A quadruple precision number? Then its probably done in software (i.e. slower). There is also `real (kind=10)`, I think.

Comment: aah `kind=10` did the trick, time is down to 12 seconds. THANKS. so apparently i was making wrong use of the `kind` parameter and the `long double` data type.

Comment: also, please write the answer with a small explanation for `kind` and `long double` that will be very helpful to a noob like me and so that i can accept it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not a Fortran expert, but it seems that

```
real (kind=16) :: ssum
```

declares a quadruple precision (16 byte) floating point number, which is probably emulated in software on your hardware. Your `C++` code uses a `long double` which corresponds to an extended precision (10 byte) floating point number, which can be done by your hardware (and is much faster). Please note that `long double` is not a 10-byte floating point number on all platforms, it may be the same thing as a `double` on some platforms, for example. I think this is true for Windows and MSVC. To get an extended precision floating point number in fortran, use:

```
real (kind=10) :: ssum
```

Comment: but `sizeof(ssum)` in my C++ code returns `16` not `10`. so is it still 10-byte precision and just taking 16 bytes in memory ?

Comment: @Guddu: Running `gcc -dM -E - < /dev/null | grep LDBL` on my machine gives `#define  __LDBL_MANT_DIG__ 64`, which is the size of the mantissa in bits. `#define __LDBL_MAX_EXP__ 16384`, `#define __LDBL_MIN_EXP__ (-16381)`, indicate that 16 bits are used to store the exponent. The size of `long double` may be larger in order to enforce proper alignment in arrays (e.g. by inserting padding bytes).

Comment: thanks, wiki page on `long double` was helpful too, it was my misunderstanding that `long double` gives twice the precision of `double`